# Unity-Mono throwing PlatformNotSupportedException while checking for Directory Permission

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

I am using below code to check Permission on Directories in Windows.

I am using in Unity 3.5.7f6 with "PC & Mac" Platforms in BuildSettings.

I am getting following exception:

1. PlatformNotSupportedException
2. UnauthorizedAccessException

   ```
   string l_userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

   DirectorySecurity folderSecurity;
   //Way 1: Getting **PlatformNotSupportedException** with below line.

   folderSecurity = new DirectorySecurity(a_directoryPath, AccessControlSections.Audit);

   //Way 1---ENDS HERE


   //Way 2: Getting **UnauthorizedAccessException** in last line of Way 2 block.

   DirectoryInfo l_directory = new DirectoryInfo(a_directoryPath);     
   folderSecurity = l_directory.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Audit);

   //Way 2---ENDS HERE

   foreach (FileSystemAccessRule fileSystemAccessRule in folderSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)))
   {

       string l_domain_userName = fileSystemAccessRule.IdentityReference.Value;
       if (l_domain_userName.Equals(l_userName))
       {
           string l_userRights = fileSystemAccessRule.FileSystemRights.ToString();
           Debug.Log(l_domain_userName + ":" + l_userRights);

           if (fileSystemAccessRule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(a_rightToCheck))
           {
               Debug.Log("-----have Accesss:" + a_rightToCheck);
               l_isGranted = true;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I have tried printing OS version:

```
Environment.OSVersion.Platform
```

it prints:
WindowsNT 5.1.2600 (which is XP)

**All i am trying above, is to get whether a folder has Permission (Read OR write).**

Help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: At the moment this feature is simply not implemented by Unity.

Unity is using a pretty old version of Mono. There seems to be some licensing issues regarding mobile platforms and consoles, so that they are not able to simple use the newest version of Mono.

As you can see in the [Mono source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono/blob/unity-4.3/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.AccessControl/DirectorySecurity.cs) for Unity 4.3, the constructor for `DirectorySecurity` simply raises an `PlatformNotSupportedException`. And because `GetAccessControl` depends on `DirectorySecurity` it will also just [raise an exception](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono/blob/unity-4.3/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/DirectoryInfo.cs#L343).

If you explain why you need the permissions or what your ultimate goal is, we may be able to find another solution for your problem.

Comment: even if the OP used a newer version of Unity, I think Unity still uses an old version of mono

Comment: thx @knocte, I didn't know Unity was still using such an old version of Mono. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Leosori. i am trying to get whether a folder has Permission (Read OR write)?

Comment: @SatbirSingh and after you know the permissions? Do you collect them for fun ;) or do you just want to write to some file(s) and check that you have permission to write?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some of **the directory security code is not implemented in a platform independent way in Mono**, even in 4.8.

I came here with a similar problem when trying to edit a folder's permissions when running Mono on a Unix box. That raised a [PlatformNotSupportedException from the NativeObjectSecurity class](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.AccessControl/NativeObjectSecurity.cs#L233) Hopefully this helps anyone else in a similar boat...